# How can I use user inputs for math?

Tags: ruby

I have this function:

```
def func()
  puts "Give a value for x \n>"
  x = gets.chomp
  puts "Give a value for y \n>"
  y = gets.chomp

  z = x + y
  puts z
end
```

If a user inputs `5` for `x` and `5` for `y`, I want `z` to make `5 + 5` and print `10`, but this will print `55` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you've read are stored as strings, and with strings, the `+` operator performs concatenation. You need to convert both inputs to integers if you want to perform integer arithmetic:

```
z = x.to_i + y.to_i
```

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. Is there a way I declare x and y as integers before asking z to sum? and another one, why would ruby take them as integers if they're not user inputs?

Comment: No, you cannot declare variables in Ruby. `gets.chomp()` returns a string, so they are strings. It's the difference between `x = 5` and `x = "5"`; one is an integer, one is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get there:

```
x = '5'
y = '5'

[x, y].map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
=> 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
z = x.to_i + y.to_i
```

Just convert input strings to integer or float (`to_f`)

Comment: Can't I just ask it as an int or float in gets?

Comment: @user2008400 try `x = gets.to_i`